# In Solr, how may I put multiple grouped data under the metadata they belong?

Tags: solr

So recently, I've been playing with a set of publishing data using Solr. The data structure is basically like this: For each page of a book, there will be a record, so if a book has 300 pages, then it will have 300 records, each have their own actual text, page numbers, etc.

The aim, aside from finding the data I want, is to group them by ISBN and showing the first three pages of the actual text inside. For the sake of example, say my current query looks like this:

```
http:(the database)select?
wt=JSON
&defType=edismax
&df=PublicationName
&fl=Title:PublicationName, Author:AuthorName, Page:Text
&qf=PublicationName OCRText
&q= Three Little Piggies, IsAuthorized:true,IsDirectory:false, IsIndex:false, IsBooktitle:false
&group=true
&group.field=ISBN
&group.limit=3
```

And as you may guess, the result will looks like this:

```
"docs": [
    {
    "Title": "Three Little Piggies",
    "Author": "Unknown",
    "Page": "Once upon a time there was an old mother pig who had three little pigs and not enough food to feed them. So when they were old enough, she sent them out into the world to seek their fortunes."
    },{
    "Title": "Three Little Piggies",
    "Author": "Unknown",
    "Page": "The first little pig was very lazy. He didn't want to work at all and he built his house out of straw. The second little pig worked a little bit harder but he was somewhat lazy too and he built his house out of sticks. Then, they sang and danced and played together the rest of the day."
    },{
    "Title": "Three Little Piggies",
    "Author": "Unknown",
    "Page": "The third little pig worked hard all day and built his house with bricks. It was a sturdy house complete with a fine fireplace and chimney. It looked like it could withstand the strongest winds."
}
]
```

So to put it straight, is there anyway I may put these three pages from the same book under a single meta data?

Edit: Supposedly more or less like this:

```
"docs": [
        {
        "Title": "Three Little Piggies",
        "Author": "Unknown",
        "Page1": "Once upon a time there was an old mother pig who had three little pigs and not enough food to feed them. So when they were old enough, she sent them out into the world to seek their fortunes."
        "Page2": "The first little pig was very lazy. He didn't want to work at all and he built his house out of straw. The second little pig worked a little bit harder but he was somewhat lazy too and he built his house out of sticks. Then, they sang and danced and played together the rest of the day."
        "Page3": "The third little pig worked hard all day and built his house with bricks. It was a sturdy house complete with a fine fireplace and chimney. It looked like it could withstand the strongest winds."
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Where does the page number come from? Can you do this when you index the content instead?

Comment: @MatsLindh While ideally I hope it will come from the page-numbers data that includes in each pages' data, here in my example the numbers are just a mere gesture to differ each pages' and their text.

Comment: You're going to have to transform the content into a single document when indexing; for each page in the book, add the page to the document under the field name as you've described (i.e. as `page<pageno>`) as shown; handling it in Solr will be cumbersome, if even possible (since they're being sent as separate updates, you'd probably have to issue atomic updates of each document in that case, and reformat the indexing request in an update chain if possible for updates).

Comment: you might be looking for [solr result grouping](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/result-grouping.html)